# 70s or 80s werewolf horror / murder mystery novel with a mountain lion "red herring"

Tags: story-identification, novel, horror, werewolf

This was a paperback I'd picked up secondhand, I'd say it's from 1970s-1980s (90s at the latest). It was a werewolf horror novel, with the main character trying to figure out who the werewolf/murderer is.

A series of animal attacks plagues a small community, and it's suspected by the main character that the perpetrator is a werewolf. At some point, there's a false resolution of the case, where a mountain lion is shot and killed and a human hand is found inside the animal's stomach upon autopsy. It's a bit like the part in *Jaws* where a different shark gets caught while the great white is still on the loose- I imagine it must have been directly inspired by it.

The main character figures out that the hand was probably shoved inside the mountain lion post-mortem by the actual murderer, who is a werewolf. He figures this out because the hand would have shown signs of being partially digested, and it was perhaps too intact for the lion to have swallowed whole. IIRC, the murderer/werewolf was the one who'd shot the mountain lion as well.

The book was in English and the setting was North America.

Any clues or guesses would be helpful, as you can imagine it's hard to search for werewolf novels now due to the amount of google results about "shifters" ebooks. It's also not *Cycle of the Werewolf* or *The Howling* (which seem to be the top results no matter what keywords I search).

Comment: Also posted at https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/x4cd10/tomt_book_1970s1980s_werewolf_murder_mystery/

Comment: Yes, that's my reddit post. I haven't had a lot of luck with book ID on that subreddit in the past and a friend suggested I try here.

Comment: We don't mind cross-posting with other non-SE sites. :) I just always like to note it to try to save people from "I found it! Oh... never mind, same question, with no answers" not to mention that when I see much a comment, I'll click into it to see if the answer was provided there. :)

Comment: That's good to know! I was a little worried I'd made a faux pas by crossposting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it myself. It's ***[Wolffile](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1560269.Wolffile)*** (1988) by Jack Woods. Checking Goodreads reviews and the text in Google Books confirmed the puma plot twist.

From [Fantastic Fiction](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/books/w/w74850.htm):

> Wolffile - neither man nor beast.... Something stalks Lugar Island. Something so vile, it defies human imagination. Something so intoxicated by the fullness of the moon, it revels in the joy of mutilation. A savage, relentless enemy filled with a rage as ancient as evil itself, it stalks its human prey, its powerful, man-wolf body pulsing with one insatiable desire to kill... Neither Islander nor mainlander Dr Ian Sanders has returned to his childhood home on Lugar Island seeking escape from the loneliness haunting him, only to be caught between two worlds, belonging to neither. When Honey Adams disappears on her wedding night, Sanders begins a search which will lead him to the terrible truths about Luna Coven...and what the full moon means for him.